# Blender 2.8 eevee render light too bright than cycle

Tags: light, lighting, eevee-render-engine

I use simple plane object with black material and put a point light above the plane. THe result is when using eevee , the light reflection is way to bright. (see the attachment : top image is cycle, bottom image is eevee). Is this my graphic card or any setting that i need to change ?

Thanks
[image]
[image]

Comment: Well, EEVEE isn't meant to be 1:1 as Cycles. Because EEVEE is something completely different than Cycles. We are talking here about ray-tracer and real time engine. You can play with Specular value under light settings but still it will not be the same as Cycles. Watch here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fAiai0fCBOw

Comment: Eevee uses Filmic as the view transform, while Cycles leaves it at the sRGB OETF I believe. Looks suspicious there...

Comment: I found out it's just the bug from previous version. When i wrote this post, the 2.8 had this bug, but it solved now. Eevee and cycle are different, but not that 'too much' different as in my screenshot. I haven't tried it again until the last couple release of Beta and it's a lot better now. Yes, they are different, but still looks correct to my eyes compared that old BUG. And since that old version is not valid anymore , i think the admin can delete this post. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

if you go into the settings of your light source you will see that the settings are different in EEVEE. changing the settings in EEVEE does not change how the light looks in cycles and vice versa. So you can tweak the settings to get the same ish result across render engines.